# SSL error (Port from Python 2.7.15 to Python 3.7.7) - HTTP Error 401: Message validation failed

Tags: python, ssl

Porting code from Python 2.7.15 to Python 3.7.7, I'm having trouble getting our SSL calls to work connecting to an in-house server.

### Running this code in each version of Python, I get:

```
import socket, ssl

context =  context = ssl.create_default_context()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
domain = 'xxx.yyy.com'
sslSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = domain)
sslSocket.connect((domain, 443))
print('the selected version by the server: ', sslSocket.cipher()[1])
```

The result in Python 2.7.15 -

('the selected version by the server: ', 'TLSv1/SSLv3')

The result in Python 3.7.7 -

the selected version by the server:  TLSv1.2

Also, I'm setting up the context as follows for my SSL calls:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

How can I set up my context in 3.7.7 to satisfy the server?

Thanks for any help!
Regards,
Michael

Steffen, thank you for your help! I've spent time investigating and posted debug logging. In Python 3.7, the first call to self._open() in urlIib2.open() returns an error handler object which contains the 401 error code.
I'm not sure if this is helpful--if there's other info I need to provide, please let me know...thank you.
I have much more info with structure content, etc., but don't want to overwhelm. Please let me know what I'm missing...

I enabled logging with the following code:

```
import requests
import logging
from http.client import HTTPConnection  # py3
log = logging.getLogger('urllib3')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# logging from urllib3 to console
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(ch)
# print statements from `http.client.HTTPConnection` to console/stdout
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
requests.get('http://httpbin.org/')
```

Here's the logging info from each test:

```
Python 2.7.15
Starting new HTTP connection (1): httpbin.org:80
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nConnection: keep- 
alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python- requests/2.19.1\r\n\r\n'
http://httpbin.org:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9593
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 19:53:40 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 9593
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true


Python 3.7.7
Starting new HTTP connection (1): httpbin.org:80
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nUser-Agent: python- requests/2.22.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
http://httpbin.org:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9593
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 20:40:58 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Content-Length: 9593
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
exception HTTP Error 401: Message validation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the wrong place for the cause of your problem.

Since you've got code 401 back this mean that the a HTTP response was received. This mean that in case of HTTPS the TLS handshake had to be successfully done since otherwise no application data (and thus no HTTP response) could have been received. Therefore the problem is very likely not with the TLS handshake but later - in code you don't show.